# Finding Minor Differences in Python Pandas Trajectories

Tags: python, pandas, csv

On github, I found a repository with tasks for practice, unfortunately there are no answers to the tasks in it.

Link to the repository: https://github.com/Hexlet/ru-test-assignments?ysclid=l7edjgc360592892479

One of the tasks I found there:

Find a slight difference between trajectory 2 and trajectory 1

The trajectories themselves look like this

```
track;time;x;y
1;10:32:13;1598;526
1;10:32:14;1524;544
1;10:32:15;1441;557
1;10:32:16;1357;392
1;10:32:17;1395;573
1;10:32:18;1352;409
1;10:32:19;1415;573
1;10:32:20;1358;379
1;10:32:21;1424;557
1;10:32:22;1319;574
1;10:32:23;1279;357
1;10:32:24;1309;573
1;10:32:25;1271;372
1;10:32:26;1294;582
1;10:32:27;1144;621
1;10:32:28;927;665
1;10:32:29;839;409
1;10:32:30;899;665
1;10:32:31;728;493
1;10:32:32;884;665
1;10:32:33;1058;391
1;10:32:34;866;665
1;10:32:35;715;684
1;10:32:36;597;509
1;10:32:37;692;684
1;10:32:38;456;425
1;10:32:39;669;684
1;10:32:40;481;719
1;10:32:41;481;684
1;10:32:42;432;693
2;10:35:17;1588;498
2;10:35:18;1438;530
2;10:35:19;1286;556
2;10:35:20;1274;325
2;10:35:21;1280;556
2;10:35:22;1264;334
2;10:35:23;1274;556
2;10:35:24;1109;595
2;10:35:25;919;637
2;10:35:26;835;375
2;10:35:27;897;636
2;10:35:28;730;468
2;10:35:29;879;637
2;10:35:30;1050;359
2;10:35:31;933;622
2;10:35:32;713;664
2;10:35:33;609;478
2;10:35:34;694;664
2;10:35:35;460;394
2;10:35:36;673;677
2;10:35:37;505;693
2;10:35:38;489;677
```

The only thing I came up with was to split the file into two frames with labels 1 and 2 and show their difference through the length of the frames

```
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv('Data\\traks.csv', delimiter = ';'))

frame1, frame2 = df.loc[df['track'].isin([1])], df.loc[df['track'].isin([2])]

if len(frame2) == len(frame1):
    out = frame1.compare(frame2)
    out.to_csv('Difference.csv', index=False)
else:
    print('The length does not match which is the difference,'
    ,'\n frame length with label 2 = ', len(frame2) 
    ,'\n frame length with label 1 = ', len(frame1)
    ,'\nThe frame with the label 1 took longer to ', len(frame1)-len(frame2))
```

This is not the right decision, is it?

Has anyone ever encountered such a thing ? Tell me what would be the most correct solution here.

Comment: What does `a slight difference between trajectory 2 and trajectory 1` really mean? If you want to find the number of rows per track, try:  `df.groupby('track').time.count()`

Comment: The thing is that in the task it is not clear what this means.  To do this, I wrote a question to understand what was meant.